# exclude node from umbraco search

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I have created umbraco search in which i want some node which should not be searched so what i can do is there something i should define in search criteria or sholud i do something in examine settings or index settings code for config files

```
 <IndexSet SetName="DemoIndexSet" IndexPath="~/App_Data/TEMP/ExamineIndexes/DemoIndex/">
<IndexAttributeFields/>
<IndexUserFields/>
<IncludeNodeTypes/>
<ExcludeNodeTypes>
<add Name="News" />
</ExcludeNodeTypes>
</IndexSet>
```

and examine setting file

```
<add name="DemoIndexer" type="UmbracoExamine.LuceneExamineIndexer, UmbracoExamine" runAsync="true"
     supportUnpublished="false"
     supportProtected="true"
     interval="10"
     analyzer="Lucene.Net.Analysis.WhitespaceAnalyzer, Lucene.Net" indexSet="DemoIndexSet"/>
```

and user control code is

```
public static class SearchResultExtensions
    {
        public static string FullUrl(this SearchResult sr)
        {
            return umbraco.library.NiceUrl(sr.Id);
        }

    }

 SearchTerm = Request.QueryString["s"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchTerm)) return;

            SearchResults = ExamineManager.Instance.SearchProviderCollection["DemoSearcher"].Search(SearchTerm,true).ToList();

            SearchResultListing.DataSource = SearchResults;
            SearchResultListing.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to exclude a node type just put this between the IndexSet tag

```
<IndexSet ...>
  ...
  <ExcludeNodeTypes>
    <add Name="NameNodeType" />
  </ExcludeNodeTypes>
</IndexSet>
```

more info on [codeplex examine](http://examine.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=UmbracoExamine)

Answer (score 3):

In your DocumentType add a field "includeInSearchIndex" of type true/false.
Then add this field in your Examine index configuration

```
<IndexUserFields>
  <add Name="includeInSearchIndex"/>
</IndexUserFields>
```

Then use a create a custom query to search for everything where this field is not checked.

```
var Searcher = ExamineManager.Instance.SearchProviderCollection["WebsiteSearcher"];            
var query = searchCriteria.Field("includeInSearchIndex", "0").
    Or().Field("includeInSearchIndex", "").Compile();
var searchResults = Searcher.Search(query);
```

Check out [this page](https://umbraco.com/blog/examining-examine/) for more info about the Examine index and the search queries